# Compute the commutator, and compare it to quantization of the Poisson bracket.

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Can someone please provide an insightful solution or verification of my solution to this question:

Compute the commutator $$[p^2,q^2]$$ (in the one variable case), and compare it to quantization $$\widehat{\{p^2, q^2\}}$$ of the Poisson bracket.

Attempted Solution:

> Recall that $$\hat{p} = - i\hbar\frac{d}{dq}$$ and that let $$\hat{q} = \hat{q}$$, hence the expression $$[\hat{p}^2,\hat{q}^2]$$ gives us:

> $$
> [\hat{p}^2,\hat{q}^2] = \hat{p}^2\hat{q}^2 - \hat{q}^2\hat{p}^2 =
> (i^2\hbar^2\frac{d^2}{dq^2}q^2) - (i^2\hbar^2 q^2\frac{d^2}{dq^2}) 
> $$
> $$\qquad 
> = (- \hbar^2\frac{d^2}{dq^2}q^2) - (- \hbar^2 q^2\frac{d^2}{dq^2})= (- \hbar^2\frac{d^2}{dq^2}q^2) + (\hbar^2 q^2\frac{d^2}{dq^2})
>  $$
> $$\qquad 
> (- \hbar^2\frac{d^2}{dq^2}q^2) + (\hbar^2 q^2\frac{d^2}{dq^2}) =
> (-2\hbar^2) + (- 2\hbar^2 q\frac{d}{dq}) = (-2i\hbar\hat{p}\hat{q}) - (2\hbar^2)$$

> Now divide by $\hbar$ and take the limit as $\hbar \to 0$, we get the following: $\frac{1}{\hbar}[\hat{p}^2,\hat{q}^2] = -2i\hat{p}\hat{q}$, and now multiply both side by $i$ to get the desired expression that:
> $\frac{i}{\hbar}[\hat{p}^2,\hat{q}^2] = \widehat{\{p^2,q^2\}}$.

Comment: These are very standard calculations. What are you having issues with?

Comment: I added my attempted solution, any feedback? @CameronWilliams

Answer (score 1):

This would have been a bland "check my homework" question, if it did not fail to specify the "quantization"
$$\widehat{\{p^2, q^2\}} = -4 \widehat{qp}.$$

For every quantization prescription, there is a different answer. For quadratic functions, all answers differ by an $\hbar$ correction, (which I think you eliminated, dangerously, by taking the $\hbar\to 0$ limit).

In any case, for *Weyl quantization*, you indeed have
$$
-2 (\hat q \hat p + \hat p \hat q),
$$
which is the exact expression determined by the commutator,
$$
-[\hat q ^2, \hat p^2]=-\{\hat q,\{\hat p,[\hat q,\hat p]\}\}= -2i\hbar (\hat q \hat p + \hat p \hat q),
$$
where, of course, now, the curly brace denotes the operator anticommutator, not the PB!